# How to loop trough a JavaScript object and change the value?

Tags: javascript

I have this as of now:

```
var text = 'This is a sentence.';
var character;
var vowelAmount = {
    a = 0,
    e = 0,
    i = 0,
    o = 0,
    u = 0
}

for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    character = text.charAt(i);
    for (var key in vowelAmount){
        if (key == character){
            vowelAmount[key]++;
        }
    }
}
for (var key in vowelAmount){
    document.write(key + '<br>');
}
```

It's supposed to display all the vowels in the text but it doesn't do anything.
I'm sure there is a way more efficient way to do this, but I would like to keep the structure since it's for school and they wan't me to use for loops...

Comment: There are basic syntax errors in your code: you can't use `=` inside objects, use `:` instead. Check your console for errors. If you want to print the count, just use `document.write(key + ': ' + vowelAmount[key] + '<br>');`. The value (in this case, the count) can be accessed by `vowelAmount[key]`.

Comment: If you want to clarify your understanding of JS objects, this is an easy place to learn basics: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment: if your code doesn't work, always remember to check your browser console first: it always contains very helpful information on what has gone wrong. In your case, the first mistake is the use of `=` in your object declaration. Use `:` instead.

Also, your code block:

```
for (var key in vowelAmount){
    document.write(key + '<br>');
}
```

...only serves to print out the *keys* in your objects (e.g. `a`), but not its value (which is the count of each vowel). To access the value in your object that is in a key-value pair, you can access it by its index, which is `vowelAmount[key]`.

See proof-of-concept below for a working example:

```js
var text = 'This is a sentence.';
var character;
var vowelAmount = {
    a: 0,
    e: 0,
    i: 0,
    o: 0,
    u: 0
}

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    character = text.charAt(i);
    for (var key in vowelAmount){
        if (key == character){
            vowelAmount[key]++;
        }
    }
}

for (var key in vowelAmount){
    document.write(key + ': ' + vowelAmount[key] + '<br>');
}
```

### Improvement notes

On a side note, I usually strongly discourage the use of `document.write` because it will overwrite whatever content you have in the document. You should create a new element instead and append them to the DOM itself. Even better: if you want your example to be 100% semantically correct, the best option is to use an unordered list.

Also, you do not need to doubly nest `for` loops: you can simply check the character against the `vowelAmount` object directly:

```js
var text = 'This is a sentence.';
var character;
var vowelAmount = {
    a: 0,
    e: 0,
    i: 0,
    o: 0,
    u: 0
}

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    character = text.charAt(i);
    if (character in vowelAmount) {
        vowelAmount[character]++;
    }
}

// Create dummy `<ul>` parent
var ul = document.createElement('ul');

// Iterate through your object and create new `<li>` element per key-value pair
// Also, once the `<li>` is created, we then inject it into `<ul>`
for (var key in vowelAmount){
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = key + ': ' + vowelAmount[key];
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

// When you're done, we can append `<ul>` to the body
document.body.appendChild(ul);
```

Comment: Also the inner loop is unneccessary and can be replaced with `if(character in vowelAmount) vowelAmount[character]++;` and the global variables are ugly.

Comment: @JonasWilms Thanks! I will include that in my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct the object creation syntax. Also note the change while displaying the count of each vowel.

```js
var text = 'This is a sentence.';
var character;
var vowelAmount = {
    a : 0,
    e : 0,
    i : 0,
    o : 0,
    u : 0
}

for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    character = text.charAt(i);
    for (var key in vowelAmount){
        if (key == character){
            vowelAmount[key]++;
        }
    }
}
for (var key in vowelAmount){
    document.write(key + '='+vowelAmount[key]+'<br>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is for school I'm not going to spoonfeed you by giving you working code, but I encourage you to look at a couple of things:

1. Your object syntax for `vowelAmount` isn't correct. Objects are set up using key-value pairs. Where the key is defined using on the left of a `:` (colon) and the value to the right of the colon. In your example, you are using `=`. This need to be a colon `:`.

   Eg:

   ```
   var person = {
     name: 'Nick', /* NOT: name = 'Nick' */
     age: 1000 /* NOT: age = 1000 */
   }
   ```
2. Your next issue is how you are displaying your values. At the moment you are only displaying the `key` in your object. If you want to display the `key` and `value` (ie the vowel and vowel count) need to access the `value` using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation).

   Eg:

   ```
   var key = 'name';
   console.log(person[key]); // gives back "Nick"
   ```

Using these ideas you should be able to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is what you are looking for.

There're several mistakes in your code.

1. JS object is wrong. Use `:` in place of `=`.
2. Two loops are unnecessary.

```js
var text = 'This is a sentence.';
var character;
var vowelAmount = {
    a: 0,
    e: 0,
    i: 0,
    o: 0,
    u: 0
}

for (const char of text) {
  if (vowelAmount.hasOwnProperty(char)) {
   vowelAmount[char] += 1; 
  }
}

console.log('vowelAmount = ', vowelAmount);
```